# Convert PDF to PNG without transparent background

Tags: php, imagick

I use the following code to convert PDF to PNG. As you can see, I use code `setImageAlphaChannel(Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_REMOVE )` to remove the background transparency. But in practice it only works for the last page. Do you think there is a problem with the code? Do you have a better solution with a higher speed?

```
$PDF = 'test.pdf';
$img = new imagick();
$img->readImage($PDF.'[0-9]'); //Convert 10 pages
$img->setImageAlphaChannel(Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_REMOVE );
$pages = count($img);
$img->writeImages('./images/'.'pdf.png', true);
```

Comment: Have you tried `$img = $img->flattenImages();` between reading and writing? https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.readimage.php

Comment: Yes. The problem with `flattenImages();` is that it combines all the pages together!

Comment: Change the second parameter of writeImages to false if you don't want all the pages together.

Comment: I changed it before. Only the first page is converted. The code states that I want the specified pages to be converted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like an iterator issue. You can try looping with something like this:

```
<?php

$PDF = 'test.pdf';
$img = new Imagick();
$img->readImage($PDF. '[0-9]');  //Convert 10 pages

$lastIndex = $img->getIteratorIndex();
$img->resetIterator();

for($i = $img->getIteratorIndex(); $i <= $lastIndex; $i++) {
    $img->setIteratorIndex($i);
    $img->setImageAlphaChannel(Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_REMOVE);
}

$pages = count($img); // not sure why you need this
$img->writeImages('./images/'.'pdf.png', true);
```

You could also get the iterating part down to a simple loop, if you like it more, since the Imagick class implements Iterator:

```
foreach($img as $i)
{
    $img->setImageAlphaChannel(Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_REMOVE);
}
```

Comment: I thought putting it in the for loop would slow it down. But no noticeable change was observed. @KevinY Thank you very much.